# Preventing contextual menu showing on specific cell in a view based NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview

Is there any way of preventing a contextual menu (and the associated selection "ring" around the cell view) being shown when **right-clicking** on a specific cell in a view-based `NSTableView` ?

I'm not talking about disabling the right-click action on ALL the cells, but only on specific ones.

I've obviously tried all the delegate methods dealing with selection changes but none works because the `selectedRow` property is not changing, only the `clickedRow` does.
So basically I'm looking for something equivalent to

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, shouldSelectRow row: Int) -> Bool
```

but for the **clicked** row not the **selected** row.

**Note**: the questions is about `NSTableView` on **macOS** and not the `UITableView`on iOS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a way to do what I wanted, although looks like a little to involved for something that should be simpler. So I welcome any simpler solution.

It can be done by subclassing NSTableView :

```
class MyTableView : NSTableView {

    override func menu(for event: NSEvent) -> NSMenu? {
        let clickedPoint = self.convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil)
        let row = self.row(at: clickedPoint)

        // no contextual menu for the last row
        return row == self.numberOfRows - 1 ? nil : super.menu(for: event)
    }
}
```

This example prevents the contextual menu to be shown for the last row, but a more generic solution could be implemented by adding a delegate with a method to return the menu for each cell.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of subclassing NSTableView, a much easier approach is to set a menu delegate and remove all items within `public func menuNeedsUpdate(_ menu: NSMenu)` delegate method.

Example:

```
class MyViewController: NSViewController  {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let menu = NSMenu()
        menu.delegate = self

        tableView.menu = menu
    }

}


extension MyViewController: NSMenuDelegate  {

    public func menuNeedsUpdate(_ menu: NSMenu) {
        //This will prevent menu from showing
        menu.removeAllItems()

        //Check if user has clicked on the cell or somewhere inside tableView 
        //area that is not populated with cells
        guard tableView.clickedRow >= 0 else { return }

        //Get model
        let item = items[tableView.clickedRow]

        //For cells that need context menu, add necessary menu items
        if item.needsContextMenu {
            menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Edit", action: #selector(tableViewEditItemClicked(_:)), keyEquivalent: "e"))
            menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Delete", action: #selector(tableViewEditItemClicked(_:)), keyEquivalent: "d"))
        }
    }

}
```